# how to use html tags in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i am calling the web api using aquery and the data that is coming consist of html tags. I removed that tags using:

```
   Html.fromHtml(Job_Desc).toString();
```

In job_desc it is having About Company,Designation and many more information. That i want to show separately. I want every heading to be in bold, for which I am using :

```
result=result.replace("Designation", Html.fromHtml("<h2><b>Designation</b></h2>"));
```

But this is not working. How do I make it work.

Comment: are you setting the text to a `TextView` ?

Comment: do **replace()** operation before **Html.fromHtml**.

Comment: no...i am storing everything in result.And setting result as a textview

Comment: [{"EVENT_TITLE":"dot net developer","Job_Desc":"<ul>\r\n\t<li>Software Engineer to work on a variety of interesting and challenging software projects. Such as advanced instructional systems, modeling and simulation based games.Should be able to work on software technical languages.</li>\r\n\t<li>candidate should have good communication skill.</li>\r\n\t<li>candidate must be pasionate towards work</li>\r\n\t<li>\r\n\t<p><span style=\"color:rgb(178, 34, 34)\"><strong>Designation:</strong>&nbsp;</span>Trainee</p>\r\n\r\n\t<p><span style=\"color:rgb(178, 34, 34)\">

Comment: Like this my data is coming

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code should be inside `<![CDATA[ YOUR HTML CODE ]]>` and assign to `Spanned` object after parsing.

Try this:

```
Spanned message = Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<h2><b>Designation</b></h2>]]>");
```

And then set this message to `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to differential Heading or highlight as Tag.. then use **tag** library using this you can easily do it, for tag libraries see https://android-arsenal.com/tag/197

better then html

Answer (score 0):

First you create string in String.xml like:

```
<string name="hello"><![CDATA[<html> <head></head><body style="text-align:justify;color:#b0b0b0;size="13";background-color:#00000000;">Yout Text Like this&#33; </body></html>]]>
```

and change special character to unicode conversion.
Then create dynamic webview like :

```
WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.loadData(getString(R.string.hello), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```